# How to join a path to a file in code, "windows safe"

Tags: uri

Given a hook (e.g. `hook_theme()`) and a path where something has to be looked up (e.g. templates), what is the cleanest way to deal with this?

I have the following directory structure:

- sites/all/modules/mymodule

  - mymodule.module
  - templates

    1. mymodule.tpl.php

When I define that path in code, I use the following code.

```
function mymodule_theme($existing, $type, $theme, $path) {
  return array(
    "mymodule"  => array(
    "variables" => array(),
    "path"      => $path . "/templates",
    "template"  => "mymodule"
  );
}
```

I want this code to work on Windows too, without having to do checks for OS inside that function.

Comment: Also bear in mind in Windows dir/file names are case insensitive, so `my_dir` & `MY_DIR` cannot exist on a windows system.

Comment: Also OS X could be case insensitive: There is a filesystem that is case-sensitive, and one that is not case-sensitive. Actually, it's an option that can be selected when formatting a device.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just use / as path separator: It will work on Windows, and any other OS.

PHP defines the `DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR` constant, but that constant is not used from Drupal core code, and Drupal works on Windows too.
A note on the parameters accepted from [basename()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.basename.php) says:

> On Windows, both slash (/) and backslash (\) are used as directory separator character. In other environments, it is the forward slash (/).